# Javascript store table in a variable with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how my page looks like:

```
<div class="bgSmTitle smTitle">Customer Addresses</div>
<table class="bgLtTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">New York</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Osaka</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Los Angeles</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="bgSmTitle smTitle">Family Members</div>
<table class="bgLtTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="bgHeader1 padded" style="width:24%;">Name</td>
    <td class="bgHeader2 padded" style="width:10%;">Relationship</td>
    <td class="bgHeader1 padded" style="width:30%;">Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Jordan</td>
    <td class="bgLtRow2 padded">Father</td>
    <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">58</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to store the tables with class name `bgLtTable`. These table can appear up to 3-4 times in this page. Is it possible to get the specific table using the div above it? Something like:

```
var tableAddress = div.innerHtml="Customer Addresses".table.bgLtTable;
var tableMembers = div.innerHtml="Family Members".table.bgLtTable;
```

Comment: A div or a table as a direct child of `tr` is not valid HTML. Whether a query selector or a DOM getter would find the wanted table from invalid HTML, is implementation-depended. I'd suggest you to fix the HTML before anything else.

Comment: @Teemu I think before it was valid because this website is very old. I just got it and was not allowed to make too many adjustments. Because they say "it works"

Comment: No, it has never been valid. There's no guarantees the code would work in all browser, since there's no standard for invalid HTML.

Comment: @Teemu Ok, so do you have answer to my question or nah.

Comment: Nobody has, it's impossible with the provided code.

Comment: @Teemu made some edit. Forgot the <td> tag after <tr>. My bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152214/discussion-between-irayan05-and-teemu).

Comment: See the [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pszh72jg/).

Comment: @Teemu I update my question to make it simpler. Your fiddle seems to work but only when there are two tables present with the same classname. Please see my edit

Comment: It works with an unspecified number of tables ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var CustomerAddressesTable = $('div.smTitle:contains("Customer Addresses")').next('.bgLtTable');
console.log($("<div />").append($(CustomerAddressesTable).clone()).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="prnt">
    <td>
      <div class="bgSmTitle smTitle">Customer Addresses</div>
      <table class="bgLtTable">
        <tr>
          <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">New York</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Osaka</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Los Angeles</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="prnt">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="bgSmTitle smTitle">Family Members</div>
      <table class="bgLtTable">
        <tr>
          <td class="bgHeader1 padded" style="width:24%;">Name</td>
          <td class="bgHeader2 padded" style="width:10%;">Relationship</td>
          <td class="bgHeader1 padded" style="width:30%;">Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">Jordan</td>
          <td class="bgLtRow2 padded">Father</td>
          <td class="bgLtRow1 padded">58</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This method will give you the html of the required table.

Comment: How can I do this in pure javascript? Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it using pure java-script. but you may have to put more effort on it. Search how to find a div containing certain text. Then its parent table.  As far as I've read, It has no direct inbuilt methods in java-script to find the parent div.

Comment: Else, give a class to parent tr's you can loop through all parents tr's. Find its inner div's(having class  smTitle) and tables. If the div(smTitle) has text 'your custom text', the set the table to a variable and break the loop. If not continue the looping till you reach your corresponding div.

Comment: @irayan05: I've provided both methods -J Query & java-script. You can prefer any one which is easiest.

Comment: I have tried your solution but the element Im getting is not a table. How can I convert this into a table? Im using the jquery way

Comment: Its an array. So CustomerAddressesTable[0] will work

Comment: This is what im getting instead of a table object. `[table.bgLtTable, prevObject: m.fn.init(1), context: document]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152220/discussion-between-gjijo-and-irayan05).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use `document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");`

This will give you an object that is accessible via index

You can then assign those elements to a variable and loop through it but look where the class attribute is equal to `className` for example

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
for (var i = 0; element.length > i; i++)
{
    var elementClass = element[i].getAttribute('class');
}
```

I am not 100% sure this answers your question how I understand is you just want to get the class.

I hope this helps I am also pretty new to coding but always willing to help if I can.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it helps you understand the problem more.